# Merge lines that share a word-link

Tags: java, arrays, string

so I'm having a small problem in java. I have something like

```
"Victor Fleming" 
"Gone With" 
"With The" 
"The Wind."
```

So what the sentence should actually look like is

```
"Victor Fleming" 
"Gone with the wind."
```

Therefore I'm looking to form a single sentence, by words that are adjacent and the same. If no adjacent same word is detected then the sentence will be separated as in "Victor Fleming" case where Fleming is not the same with Gone, so a new sentence is starting. What I've written so far:

```java
List<String> separatedText = new ArrayList<>();
int i = 0;
while (i < mergedTextByHeightColor.size()) {
    if ((i < (mergedTextByHeightColor.size() - 3)) && !(mergedTextByHeightColor.get(i + 1).equals(mergedTextByHeightColor.get(i + 2)))) {
        separatedText.add(mergedTextByHeightColor.get(i) + " " + mergedTextByHeightColor.get(i + 1));
        i = i + 2;
    }
    String concatStr = "";
    while ((i < (mergedTextByHeightColor.size() - 3)) && (mergedTextByHeightColor.get(i + 1).equals(mergedTextByHeightColor.get(i + 2)))) {
        if (concatStr.contains(mergedTextByHeightColor.get(i))) {
            concatStr = mergedTextByHeightColor.get(i + 1) + " " + mergedTextByHeightColor.get(i + 3);
        } else {
            concatStr = mergedTextByHeightColor.get(i) + " " + mergedTextByHeightColor.get(i + 1) + " " + mergedTextByHeightColor.get(i + 3);
        }
        i = i + 3;
    }
    separatedText.add(concatStr);
}
```

Comment: What is your desired behavior? Your current description is too confusing.

Comment: Question: How do you know that "Victor Fleming" should be kept together as a single "sentence"? "Victor" and "Fleming" are different words that are adjacent so shouldn't they be separated?

Comment: As in the example above: "Victor Fleming Gone With With The The Wind". I want to get "Victor Fleming" and "Gone with the Wind" in two separate sentences, since it can be seen that "Gone With With The The Wind" can be merged into "Gone with the Wind" due to adjacent duplicate words, in a single sentence, whereas Victor Fleming can't. So what I've tried to do is get the words on position a+1 and a+2 and see if they are the same. If they are not then the sentence will only be formed by word on position a and position a+1 (since no continuos merging of duplicates words can be done).

Comment: @Code-Apprentice My bad, I'm getting the words on separate lines like this "Victor Fleming" "Gone With" "With The" and so on. I know that the first word from that pair can't be the same with the second word in the pair. However the second word in the pair could be the same with the first word from the next pair. I wrote the problem wrong when saying adjacent, my bad

Comment: @Simm You should edit the question to show the proper input instead of describing it in the coments. I have edited it to my understanding. Feel free to edit it again if I misunderstood anything.

Comment: What happens when you run your code? What output do you get? What do you want it to be instead? I suggest reading [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code. It will also help if you back up a step and think about how you would solve this problem by hand. Describe in words what steps you would take to do it.

Comment: I'm getting the error  ``` "    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 420546432 byte allocation with 25165824 free bytes and 241MB until OOM, max allowed footprint 308428912, growth limit 536870912
" ``` At separatedText.add(concatStr), just at the last word that needs to be added, otherwise it works fine. But I'm blocked at this line..

Comment: How big is your input file? The error looks like you are trying to allocate 4 GB of memory, which seems like way too much for a toy problem like this.

Comment: With that said, I think you need to find a different approach to your problem. It might help to rethink how you are parsing the input text. How do you create `mergedTextByHeightColor`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can store the sentences in a String array, then loop through each one.

Inside the loop, we check whether the last word of the last item (by splitting it into an array with `.split(" ")`, then getting the last element) is equal to the first word of the current item. If it is, we first remove the first word of the current item, then append it to a `StringBuilder`.

If it isn't, then we append the StringBuilder's value to the list, append the current element, and move on.

```
String[] sentences = {"Victor Fleming", "Gone With", "With The", "The Wind."};
List<String> newsentences = new ArrayList<>();
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
for(int i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++) {
    String cur = sentences[i];
    if(i != 0) {
        String[] a = sentences[i-1].split(" ");
        String[] b = cur.split(" ");
        String last = a[a.length-1];
        String first = b[0];
        if(last.equalsIgnoreCase(first)) {
            str.append(cur.substring(first.length()));
        }else {
            newsentences.add(str.toString());
            str = new StringBuilder();
            str.append(cur);
        }
    }else {
        str.append(cur);
    }
}
newsentences.add(str.toString());
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newsentences.toArray()));
```

Output:

```
[Victor Fleming, Gone With The Wind.]
```